# PayPal payment stuck "processing"

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I've implemented the latest PayPal API but every time I try to run the payment through PayPal's sandbox the payment just gets stuck on "Processing." Totally stumped. Thanks!

```
-(void)payWithPayPal {
    NSString *shortDescription = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i %@", [Global sharedInstance].currentOrder.itemQuantity, [Global sharedInstance].currentOrder.boozeBrand];
    NSDecimalNumber *paymentDecimal = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", [Global sharedInstance].currentOrder.itemPrice]];
    NSString *sku = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DBAR-%i", [Global sharedInstance].currentOrder.orderNumber];

    NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [Global sharedInstance].currentOrder.boozeBrand];
    PayPalItem *item = [PayPalItem itemWithName:name
                                withQuantity:[Global sharedInstance].currentOrder.itemQuantity
                                       withPrice:paymentDecimal
                                    withCurrency:@"USD"
                                         withSku:sku];
    float priceFloat = [item.price floatValue];
    float totalFloat = priceFloat * item.quantity;
    NSDecimalNumber *total = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", totalFloat]];

    PayPalPayment *payment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init];
    payment.amount = total;
    payment.currencyCode = @"USD";
    payment.shortDescription = shortDescription;
    payment.items = nil;  // if not including multiple items, then leave payment.items as nil
    payment.paymentDetails = nil; // if not including payment details, then leave payment.paymentDetails as nil

    if (!payment.processable) {NSLog(@"Payment not processable.");}

    // Update payPalConfig re accepting credit cards.

    PayPalPaymentViewController *paymentViewController = [[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc] initWithPayment:payment configuration:self.payPalConfiguration delegate:self];
    [self presentViewController:paymentViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}


#pragma mark - PayPalDelegate

-(void)payPalPaymentViewController:(PayPalPaymentViewController *)paymentViewController willCompletePayment:(PayPalPayment *)completedPayment completionBlock:(PayPalPaymentDelegateCompletionBlock)completionBlock {
    NSLog(@"Payment processing.");
    //Stuck on this forever - this is what I'm trying to get past
}

-(void)payPalPaymentViewController:(PayPalPaymentViewController *)paymentViewController didCompletePayment:(PayPalPayment *)completedPayment {
    //Never gets here
}
```

Comment: at which step it stuck? did the login popup shown and after at the payment it is stuck ? also does this happen in their demo also with your credentials ?

Comment: Login window is fine, credentials passed, then it pops back to the screen where you selected payment. I select payment, then it just is stuck on processing. In their demo it works just fine with my credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You issue is in the completion block of `willCompletePayment`, you need to return the completion block after you have complete the processing in that 
to call the `didCompletePayment`

From Paypal code documentation

> Your code MUST finish by calling the completionBlock.
>   completionBlock Block to execute when your processing is done.

so your code will be like

```
- (void)payPalPaymentViewController:(nonnull PayPalPaymentViewController *)paymentViewController
                willCompletePayment:(nonnull PayPalPayment *)completedPayment
                    completionBlock:(nonnull PayPalPaymentDelegateCompletionBlock)completionBlock {
    //do all the code you want
    completionBlock();
}
```

After you write this completion block it will go to `didCompletePayment`, which can be like this:

```
- (void)payPalPaymentViewController:(PayPalPaymentViewController *)paymentViewController didCompletePayment:(PayPalPayment *)completedPayment {
  NSLog(@"PayPal Payment Success!");
  self.resultText = [completedPayment description];
  [self showSuccess];
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**Another Option**
By checking the code of Paypal example, it is not compulsory to implement the `willCompletePayment` method, you can skip this method and directly write `didCompletePayment`

in this way your code can be like this:

```
- (void)payPalPaymentViewController:(PayPalPaymentViewController *)paymentViewController didCompletePayment:(PayPalPayment *)completedPayment {
  NSLog(@"PayPal Payment Success!");
  self.resultText = [completedPayment description];
  [self showSuccess];

  [self sendCompletedPaymentToServer:completedPayment]; // Payment was processed successfully; send to your server for verification and fulfillment
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Code documentation for the `didCompletePayment` from Paypal

> Your code MAY deal with the completedPayment, if it did not already do
>   so within your optional
>   payPalPaymentViewController:willCompletePayment:completionBlock:
>   method.

By using that method you don't need to call `willCompletePayment` method and you will not face the issue which you have faced.

Comment: Thank you SO much - total lifesaver.